# C: loop over fgets digit by digit lean for strange behavior

Tags: c

I want to implement simple task:

I have single line input with `numbers`:

```
2 1 2 3
```

And i want to print it so currently this works fine for most of scenarios:

```
char str[512];

for (i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++)
{
    if (str[i] != '\0' && !isspace(str[i]))
    {
        int num = atoi(&str[i]);
        printf("%d ", num);

    }
}
```

Now in case my input is with `number` with mote then one `digit` things start to mess.

For example:

```
2 12
```

In this case i can see that i have this input:

```
2 12 2
```

So in case i have `number > 9` i can just raise `i` by `1`:'

```
if (i > 9)
  i++;
```

And in case my `number` is with 3 `digits` i can just do `i+=2` but is there is another solution maybe that is more 'clean' ?

**EDIT**

```
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

char *ptr;
long ret;

for (i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++)
{
    if (str[i] != '\0' && !isspace(str[i]))
    {
        ret = strtol(str[i], &ptr, 10);
        printf("%ld\n", ret);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already found out what's wrong with your solution. The idea you present is bad, what if the string contains something like `01`? This is two characters, but still smaller than 10.

There are several possibilities to do better, I can think of two approaches immediately:

- instead of `atoi()`, use `strtol()` (you should anyways). `strtol()` has a parameter `endptr` -- pass it the address of a `char *` pointer, then this pointer will point to the first character that *wasn't* converted. To use this, you must probably rewrite your loop to use pointers. Here's an example:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <ctype.h>

  char str[512] = "2 15 42 7 11";

  int main(void)
  {
      for (const char *c = str; *c;)
      {
          if (!isspace(*c))
          {
              char *endptr;
              long num = strtol(c, &endptr, 10);
              if (endptr == c) exit(1);   // nothing was converted, just error out here
              printf("%ld\n", num);
              c = endptr;
          }
          else
          {
              ++c;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Even simpler, if it doesn't matter to destroy your input string in the course, use `strtok()` (see [the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) for how it works) to *split* your strings at the whitespace, like `strtok(str, " \t\n")` in the first iteration and `strtok(0, " \t\n")` in the subsequent iterations. Then you can just convert the parts you get from `strtok()`.

Comment: Please see my edit, this works only for str, and then prong the first number several times, if i change it inside the  for to str[i] this crash

Comment: @DanaYeger the code in your edit is chaos, as I wrote, you need to **make use** of `endptr` and therefore have to rewrite your loop to operate on pointers. See the example I edited in.

Comment: Why i need this code: const char *c = str ?

Comment: Initialize your pointer to the start of your input string? The loop operates on the pointer now (instead of on an index).